# How to get video format from video URL (Any type, not just AVPlayer compatible)

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, avplayer, tvos

I want to get the format from a video URL (mp4, m3u8, mpeg etc...) to decided which player to use in my app (AVPlayer or third party).

One option is to check if AVAsset(...).isPlayable, Im using this right now, but I want to improve my logic for when the AVPlayer can't be used.

When I can't use AVPlayer then I encode the video using ffmpeg, if I could have the format of the video (and maybe even more information) I could improve the encode done by ffmpeg.

Comment: You can get the url type identifier

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Regex expression to analyse the URL and find the extension.

you can use this one : **.\w{3,4}($|?)**

Comment: Why would you use a regex if all you need is to get the url [pathExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1410208-pathextension)?

Comment: The URL sometimes does not have an extension, it may redirect you to another URL

Answer (score 0):

If you do NOT want to use Regex, then this code should do the trick :

```
var url = "https://www.bruno.com/videos/video.mp4"

extension String {

    func fileExtension() -> String {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self).pathExtension
    }
}

let fileExtension = url.fileExtension()

print(fileExtension)
```

Comment: The URL sometimes does not have an extension, it may redirect you to another URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
let url = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")

let result = url?.pathExtension
    //result will return the extension of the given path
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The URL sometimes does not have an extension, it may redirect you to another URL

Comment: Could you please provide any dummy url without any extension to verify the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ffmpeg you could do an ffprobe on the url to get the codec_name.

Something like this should work:

`ffprobe test.mp4 -show_streams -show_entries stream=codec_type,codec_name, -of json -v quiet`